# How does a shell script read command handle unused columns when reading a CSV?

Tags: bash, shell

I am inspecting a shell script that is used to read a CSV file and then insert the data into a database.

The script has a structure similar to

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME='MyFile.csv'
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
LINE=0
while read foo bar baz boo
do
    LINE=$(($LINE+1));
    if [ $LINE != 1 ]
    then
        if [ -z "$bar" ]
        then
            bar=-1
        fi
        if [ -z "$baz" ]
        then
            baz=-1
        fi
        if [ -z "$boo" ]
        then
            boo='NULL'
        fi
fi

done <$FILENAME
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

If my CSV file has the structure

```
foo, bar, baz, boo, zee, wee
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
```

how does `read` react to not reading in the last two columns? I assume that data is just ignored and during every iteration of the loop only the first four columns are read into the variables?

I also cannot find any information about the `-z` in the `if fi` statements, I assume that it stands for "if value equals zero"?

Comment: Don't change the value of `IFS` globally; just prefix it to the `read` command. `while IFS=, read foo bar baz boo; do`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) (emphasis mine):

> One line is read from the standard input, or from the file descriptor *fd* supplied as an argument to the `-u` option, and the first word is assigned to the first *name*, the second word to the second *name*, and so on, **with leftover words and their intervening separators assigned to the last *name*.**

So in your case, `boo` will have the remaining data from each line.

The `-z` test is also described in the Bash Manual under [Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions). In short:

> True if the length of *string* is zero.

Answer (score 2):

`read` does not ignore the last two columns; it simply stops splitting early. If you examine the value of `boo`, you'll see that it contains something like `boo, zee, wee` as its value. You need at least one more variable to hold the trailing cruft:

```
while IFS=, read foo bar baz boo everythingelse; do
    ...
done < "$FILENAME"
```

`-z` tests the length of the string argument. To test for a value of zero, you need to use `=` (or `-eq`, if you know the string looks like an integer).

```
if [ "$bar" -eq 0 ]; then
    bar=-1
fi
```

Note that the whitespace following the comma is *not* stripped from the value of the variables. The value of `bar` on the first line is `<space>2`, not `2`.